# CDF of mins and max's of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a uniform random variable on $[0, 2]$. I just wanted to check some basic problems regarding CDFs.

(i) What is the CDF of $Y = max\{1, X\}$ and (ii) What is the CDF of $Z = min\{X, X^2\}$?

For (i) I want to say that $F_Y(t) = 0$ if $t \leq 1$, and then for $t \in [1, 2)$, $F_Y(t) = (t-1)/2$ since the relevant part is $X$ being between $1$ and $t$ only. And then at $t = 2$ we have a discontinuous jump up to $F_Y(2) = 1$ at which point it is constant. Does this sound right?

(ii) is a bit more complicated I guess. $F_Z(t) = 0$ for $t \leq 0$ obviously. But for $t \in [0, 1]$, $X^2 \leq X$ always holds, so $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(X^2 \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq \sqrt{t}) = \sqrt{t}/2$, so $F_Z(t) = \sqrt{t}/2$ on $t \in [0, 1]$. Then from $t \in [1, 2]$ onwards, we always have that $X \leq X^2$, so that $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq t) = 1/2 + \mathbb{P}(1 \leq X \leq t)  = 1/2 + (t-1)/2 = t/2$, and so $F_Z(t) = t/2$ for $t \in [1, 2]$ and is a constant $1$ from that point onwards. I'm less sure about this since it is continuous which seems unlikely to me, and my logic feels sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

> For (i) I want to say that $F_Y(t) = 0$ if $t \leq 1$, and then for $t \in [1, 2)$, $F_Y(t) = (t-1)/2$ since the relevant part is $X$ being between $1$ and $t$ only. And then at $t = 2$ we have a discontinuous jump up to $F_Y(2) = 1$ at which point it is constant. Does this sound right?

Not quite.  That is not at all correct on the discontinuity issue, but you are correct in other aspects.

There is no step discontinuity at $t=2$, that is just where the CDF stops increasing (when it reaches $1$).   The function is not smooth there, but it is continuous.   $$\lim_{t\nearrow 2}F_Y(t)=1\\\lim_{t\searrow 2}F_Y(t)=1$$

The step discontinuity occurs at $t=1$, because there all the mass of $\{X\leqslant 1\}$ is concentrated. That is to say $\mathsf P(\max\{1,X\}<1)=0$ and $\mathsf P(\max\{1,X\}=1)=\mathsf P(X\leqslant 1)$.

$$\lim_{t\nearrow 1} F_Y(t)=0\\\lim_{t\searrow 1} F_Y(t)=1/2$$

For all $t$ at and above $1$ (and below $2$), then the CDF for $Y$ equals the CDF for $X$.  So your evaluation in the parts is correct.

$$F_Y(t) =\begin{cases} 0 & : & t<1 \\ t/2 &:& 1\leqslant t < 2\\1 &:& 2\leqslant t\end{cases}$$

---

> (ii) is a bit more complicated I guess.

Just a bit, but not that much.  You are correct that the function partitions at $X=1$, and about the evaluation in each part, but the function is continuous at that point.

$$F_Z(t) = \begin{cases}0&:& t<0\\ \sqrt{t~} / 2&:& 0\leqslant t<1\\ t / 2&:& 1\leqslant t< 2\\1&:& 2\leqslant t\end{cases}$$

---

Long story short.  Don't confuse continuity of the function with continuity of the gradient.